# Cross-platform - Which application to develop in

Tags: android, ios, html, flash, cross-platform

We've been making our smaller aplications in FlashBuilder, but now we need to make our apps work on multiple platforms. (iOS/Android phone and tablets)

What should the apps do?
It's rather simple. It's a video player. We build an application that presents you with a menu, where you can navigate to submenus and click to see videos or images.

Functionality needs:
So what we need is basically a way to build a nice interface with buttons for navigation, and the ability to show images and play video clips. All offline.

What would be the best way to do this?

I was thinking about HTML5 maybe, but hos do you make an offline site and put that on an iPad with all the assets?

Any tips, ideas or feedback would be great :)

Thanks!

Comment: phoneGap is the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your functional needs, ie does the content have to be available offline etc, do you need access to phone specific API's (camera, gps etc) I would suggest looking at either of the following platforms:

Sencha Touch & Phonegap (Cordova)

Essentially in both you create a web interface which is then compiled onto the device using native features. Both frameworks give you access to the phones native functions such as camera, accelerometer etc. However in their core they are still websites.

This way you can use most of the same code base to reach multiple platforms. Be aware that minor difference might still be unavoidable between android/ios etc.

An alternative road to look at is still Flash, as you can deploy to the various mobile devices natively as well. Unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience with this so I can't really advise if this is the way to go.

There are a lot of options here and the tradeoff will always be around development time, cost and maintainability & performance. Although both platforms mentioned above will get the job done, you will get the best performance by creating a native app on iOS & Android. However since you essentially use the same code base in Phonegap & Sencha it would be easier to maintain.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer! :) The applications will be offline, and as far as I know I will not need any phone specific functions (other than touch support, of course ^^). I'll have a look at Phonegap and see if that might be a solution for me.